# The Right,Left columns are not visible in Bootstrap Layout

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am doing 1 layout using bootstrap,in there header and footer and middle areas are displayed.But left and right columns are not displayed.My code is below.

```
<!doctype html>
   <html>
    <head>
    <title>My First Bootstrap Project</title>
     <meta charset="utf-8">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
   </head>

   <body>
  <div class="container" style="height:1000px; width:1000px; margin-left:auto;    margin-right:auto;">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-12 well header" style="background:#E5E4E2; height:200px;">    </div>
 </div>
   <div class="row">

     <div class="col-md-3 well left" style="background:black; height:600px;  float:left;"> </div>
      <div class="col-md-6 well middle" style="background:yellow;  height:600px;"> </div>
     <div class="col-md-3 well right" style="background:black; height:600px;  float:right;"></div>
    </div>
  <div class="row"> 
   <div class="col-md-12 well footer" style="background:#E5E4E2; height:200px;"> </div>
  </div>  
 </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You don't really need to float your left and right DIV elements. Other than that, given that you have a proper reference to bootstrap and your screen is wide enough, you shouldn't have problems. Keep in mind that if your screen is narrower than what bootstrap media tags designate as 'md' then your elements will stack vertically instead of horizontally. (keep in mind you didn't provide any css you have written so if that is messing something up we wouldn't know since we can't see it)

Comment: what is that reference?? please explain ,i am new to bootstrap.

Comment: I'm talking about this `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">` If the `href` part of the link element is wrong, the .css file won't be loaded and your page will load without bootstrap. Something I would recommend is to replace it with this `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">` It is Bootstrap's CDN found [here](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/)